# Chrome 37.0.2062.102m disallowing google fonts

Tags: html, google-chrome, fonts

I am getting the following error when using the newest version of Chrome:

> Redirect at origin 'http://fonts.gstatic.com' has been blocked from
>   loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: The request was
>   redirected to a URL ('about:blank') which has a disallowed scheme for
>   cross-origin requests.

Seems to be working on other devices...  Here's my font code:

```
link href ="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700,300italic,400italic"
rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  (in carats)
```

Web page: frew-law.com

Just noticed, proper fonts working in incognito mode.

Any way to fix?  Or just wait for next chrome fix?

Comment: what version of chrome are you using?

Comment: Works fine here, although you have a JS error.

Comment: i accessed the site frew-law it works fine for me as well i have chrome Version 34.0.1838.2

Comment: As stated in the Title: Version 37.0.2062.102 m

Comment: Possible solution?  I have recently installed extension Disconnect... on that page I allowed google, etc. and fonts look appropriate.

Comment: I've been having the same issue in Chrome and FF latest versions. For me it was on the ISP side. Everything worked fine when I changed my connection to a different source. I recently had a new fiber router installed, so I think that may he the issue. It's working fine for me now, even with Disconnect active.

Answer (score 1):

Try accessing the fonts using https instead of http. That got rid of the CORS error for me.